# How can you show that an orthonormal basis can be expressed as the sum of a different orthonormal basis and the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, orthogonality, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

Hi!

I understood from this question ([Orthonormal basis question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5UY1.png)) that we have to show that an orthonormal basis can be expressed as the sum of a different orthonormal basis and the standard basis, in two different steps. I have tried to write it out, but I get stuck every time. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Any help would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the '*sum of a different orthonormal basis and the standard basis*', but rather '*linear combination of another orthonormal basis*'.

Well, it's not said, but the notation suggests, and if it feels better, we can calmly assume that $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$.
Nevertheless, it's enough to assume that it's an orthonormal basis.

For 1. simply use that $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ is a *basis*, and hence any vector - and thus in particular the vectors $f_k$ - can be expressed by a unique linear combination of them.

For 2., note that the $i$th column ${\bf q}_i=(q_{i1},\dots,q_{in})^T$ of $Q$ is the coordinate vector of $f_i$ coordinatized in $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$, and prove that $\langle {\bf q}_i,\,{\bf q}_j\rangle\,=\,\langle f_i,f_j\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you! My professor indeed changed the question to vector g instead of e, because of the ambiguity of e being the standard vector... But I understand part 1 very clearly now! However, I'm still struggling with part 2. I really don't see the link between the inner products of the coordinate vector q and the vector f being the same and orthogonality. I hope you don't mind elaborating on that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Let's denote the standard basis by $u_i$, it's also orthonormal. Then we have ${\bf q}_i=\sum_j q_{ij}u_i$ while $f_i=\sum_j q_{ij}e_i$. Form the inner product of two such and use that $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. I understand you can write qi as a linear combination of the q and the basis vector and that you can write f as a linear combination of q and the vector e, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Which part is not clear? (1) why $\langle q_i,q_j\rangle=\langle f_i,f_j\rangle$? Or (2) how it implies that $Q$ is orthogonal? For (1) you should finish the calculation in my previous comment (probably renaming the indices). For (2), how do you define orthogonal matrix?

Comment: The first part. I don't understand what you mean with this sentence: "Form the inner product of two such and use that ⟨ui,uj⟩=⟨ei,ej⟩". Do you mean the inner product of q and f? How can I do that by using the fact that they are linear combinations?

Comment: The point is that $f_i$ and $q_i$ have the exact same coordinates, though in different orthonormal bases. If $a=\sum a_ie_i$ and $b=\sum b_ie_i$ then $\langle a,b\rangle=\sum a_ib_i$ for *any* orthonormal basis $e_i$.

Comment: However, I particularly meant $\langle q_i,q_j\rangle=\sum_{k,l}q_{ik}q_{jl}\langle u_k,u_l\rangle$, and use *here* that $\langle u_k,u_l\rangle=\langle e_k,e_l\rangle$.

Comment: However, as I hinted in my answer, we can get an easier proof by first assuming $e_i=u_i$ the standard basis. Then the statement should be clear based on your current understanding. Now, for an arbitrary orthonormal basis $e_i$ just form its own orthogonal matrix relative to the standard basis $u_i$, and observe that the transition matrix $e_i\mapsto f_i$ is the composite $Q_fQ_e^{-1}$, which is thus also orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry, I really lost track... It's really chaotic in my mind. Why do the q here ⟨qi,qj⟩=∑k,lqikqjl⟨uk,ul⟩ have to subscripts, i and k and j and l? The q are just the coordinates in the linear combination, right? Or do we see them as vectors? Do you mean with using ⟨uk,ul⟩=⟨ek,el⟩ that those are both 0?

Comment: Yes, they are either both $0$ or $1$ if $k=l$. The $q_i$ here is the ${\bf q}_i$ in my answer, it's a vector just as $f_i$. I defined $q_i$ to have the same coordinates in the standard basis as $f_i$ in the basis $e_j$. The numbers $q_{ij}$ constitute the matrix $Q$ which we want to prove is orthogonal. $q_i$ is just its $i$th column (or row.. I never know:)

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out for the last hour... Sorry that I keep coming back to you. Could you please try to give a clear step-by-step explanation? I keep getting confused because I feel like there are a lot of different ways to do it and different notations and that's why I lose track. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Let $e_i$ and $f_i$ be orthonormal bases. Let $Q$ be the matrix with $i$th columns  the coordinates $q_{ij}$ of $f_i$ in basis $e$. I defined $q_i$ to be the $i$th column of the matrix, thus with same coordinates as $f_i$ but in the *standard basis*. Then I claimed $\langle q_i,q_j\rangle=\langle f_i,f_j\rangle$ which proves that $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. If you insert the coordinates of $q_i$ for calculating the left side, ....

Comment: ..then you'll have $\sum_{k,l} q_{ik}q_{jl}\langle u_k, u_l\rangle=\sum_k q_{ik}q_{jk}$. If you do the same with the right hand side, $\langle f_i, f_j\rangle$ will yield the same.